# How to fix buttons from the bottom in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_header"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_version"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/about_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/environment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button_privacy_policy"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/about_privacy_policy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button_terms_and_conditions"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/about_terms_and_conditions"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to have a big space between the image and the two buttons on the bottom. Something like:

```
[title]
[title]
[image]



[Button]
[Button]
```

I used `marginTop` but in some devices you can't see the bottom. I would like to use something more robust. I'm using API 16. Is there a way to fix the two buttons to be for example "15dp" from the bottom?

Comment: Try `ConstraintLayout`? Then you could constraint the buttons to the bottom of the parent and the title to the top of the parent. (Edit: but why do you have it in a ScrollView if you want it all to be seen anyway?)

Comment: marginTop is the best way to go in my opinion and it should work in all devices. If it doesn't work in "some devices" then it should be another issue which you need to test by checking the layout inspector on this specific device.

Comment: Why don't you use a [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) and constrain the `Buttons` to the `bottom` of the `parent` and other views to the `top` of the `parent`? Using fixed `marginTop` obviously gives you problem in small screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code   **android:layout_gravity="bottom"**
hope it will work for you

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_button_terms_and_conditions"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/about_terms_and_conditions"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Tag

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```